# RxBinding or RxAndroid

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-binding

I do not have very clear these two concepts, as they relate `RxBinding` and `RxAndroid`.

`RxBinding` is used for the view, can I use `RxAndroid` without using `RxBinding`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding):

> RxJava binding APIs for Android UI widgets from the platform and
>   support libraries.

[RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid):

> Reactive Extensions for Android.
>
> Android specific bindings for RxJava 2.
>
> This module adds the minimum classes to RxJava that make writing
>   reactive components in Android applications easy and hassle-free. More
>   specifically, it provides a Scheduler that schedules on the main
>   thread or any given Looper.

Don't get confused by the binding word in the *Android specific bindings for RxJava 2* .

And the answer is **YES** . You can use RxAndroid without the RxBinding library. They are not related.